# PHP coding - A class for each view or one class to rule them all?

Tags: php, class

I am starting my first "programming" project in PHP making some sort of web application that give the linux program, Motion, a decent web interface.

Anyways, I was curious as to how when real applications are programmed, do y'all go for a class for each view or one single class for the application altogether? I know this is more of a preference thing, I was just curious as to how it happens in real software.

Comment: If you would make a single class for the whole application, the class would probably become immensely huge.... which is not good!

Comment: I should have said that one differently!

Comment: Check symfony too: http://www.symfony-project.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a framework like CodeIgniter or CakePHP. It separates your model (database), views (the HTML), and controllers (application logic). MVC is the way of future programming...

Comment: Haha, thanks man, but it's best I fight it out from scratch to learn the language a bit more!

Comment: @Seth. I did NOT downvote you. I (almost) never downvote. Unless the answer is really bad.

Comment: @alfred - apologies. Someone did, i assumed it was you. again, sorry for the accusation :)

Comment: @Seth no problem. Your answer isn't even that bad(and deserves an upvote which I will give you). But "wave of future programming". I find the wave word in it very strange.

Comment: @alfred - it was supposed to be "way" but my brain told my hands to type "wave" - its been updated - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Views are generally not classes, but template files containing HTML with placeholders or echo statements. In that case, a single View class is required to parse the template file and display it.

Of course, each view can have its own instance (i.e.: an object) of the View rendering class and be called separately.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a class for each view. You could watch [codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/watch/blog/)'s screencasts to give you some guidance how to use MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's your understanding of a "view". If you think of the [Model-View-Controller-Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), you definitely should create one class per view.

If you didn't had the MVC pattern in mind, I assume that "view" means the whole page which is displayed at a time. Then you should try to create components (aka widgets) instead of views. So that you can create pages by combining those components. It will make reuse and refactoring easier. But I know that PHP will make it difficult, because it is not component-based and you will have an hard time to seperate the life-cycles of the components.

Also notice that there is a [front-controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FrontController), which will route all requests through a single class, but it is only routing requests and not rendering the whole "view".

Comment: I have separate views pages that each have a whole bunch of stuff going on, so I chose to go with a class to do all the things for each place. Works out fine for me!